# Localize Ember-power-select "No results found" text

Tags: ember.js, ember-power-select

I am having a hard time finding out how to localize this string that appears to be coming from ember-power-select: "No results found"

[image: "No results found" text in dropdown]

This string is nowhere to be found in our app's codebase.

Searching around google did not yield any results, so, while the solution may be in the docs, it'd be nice to have an easy to find stack overflow page linking to it.

EDIT: In the docs, I see I should use the `noMatchesMessage`: http://ember-power-select.com/docs/api-reference (I'll also be setting `loadingMessage` and `searchMessage`)

### HOWEVER

I don't know how to set these options globally.

Comment: Did you considered to extend the component by your default implementation to change the default `noMatchesMessage`?

Comment: I did think of creating a new component that simply wraps power-select.. I guess that wouldn't be so bad, search and replace all `{{#power-select` references in *.hbs files with `{{#localized-power-select`

Comment: You could also create a component in your application with the same name that extends power-select. But could get confusing since application power-select component behaves different from docs then. Another option would be to reopen power-select component.

Answer (score 3):

In the docs, use the `noMatchesMessage`: http://ember-power-select.com/docs/api-reference